# Last clicked DIV permanent colour, for some reason not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to emulate this on my design: http://jsfiddle.net/AYRh6/26/
But it's not working, and I can't find anything in the code that may be stopping it.
Must say I'm using code for a toggle effect.

Any help is much appreciated.

Fiddle of my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Gr8sw/

My HTML is:

```
    <div id="category">
         <section id="pushOne" class="slidebox">
        <div class="toggle">
            <a class="bot" href="#"><img src="01.png" alt="Category 1"/></a>
                <a class="top" href="#pushOne"><img src="01.png" alt="Category 1"/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="box"><h2>Category 1</h2>   
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin facilisis    aliquet odio, dictum hendrerit metus egestas non. Ut quis est tellus. Duis luctus elit nec arcu bibendum lacinia. Quisque luctus orci lorem, sit amet consequat enim mollis quis. Nullam dui magna, aliquam non venenatis et, lobortis eget felis. 
            </div>
         </section> 
</div>
```

And my CSS is:

```
.toggle {
    height:230px;
    width:230px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
    background:#CECECE;
}


.toggle:hover, .toggle.clicked {background:#F05A24;}

.orange {background#F05A24;}

.toggle img {width:100%;}

#pushOne img {padding-top:20px;}


.toggle a { position: absolute; padding:40px;}

.box {
    overflow:hidden;
    display:hidden;
    opacity:0;
    transition: all .4s ease-out;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    width:230px;
}


.slidebox:target .box {
    min-height:100px;
    opacity:1;
}


.slidebox {float:left; margin:0 50px 0 0; transition: all 0.2s ease;}
.slidebox:target .top { opacity:0; pointer-events: none;}


#category {margin:0 auto;width:80%;}
```

Javascript:

```
$(".toggle").click(function () {
   $(this).toggleClass(".clicked");
});</script>
```

It's surely something that my eye is not catching :(

Comment: Questions about problems with code should only include relevant code. Please edit your code to only include all *relevant* code. Remove anything that is not related to your problem (both in the html and in the css).

Comment: I've just edited it so that it includes relevant code. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Itay, that fiffle isn't mine; I'm mentioning it as a reference for the effect I'm looking to achieve.

Comment: Than make a fiddle reproducing your problem.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Gr8sw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You havn't specified any css propertiies for the class clicked(the class you want to toggle into)

Remove the dot(.).

```
$(".toggle").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
});
```

Include externel jquery source please
    http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js

Comment: .toggle.clicked {background:#F05A24;}

Comment: $(".toggle").click(function () {
   $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
});</script>

Comment: Dude, you havent included the jquery part.
     http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js include this please
see http://jsfiddle.net/Gr8sw/26/

Comment: Holy s... Stress is taking its toll on me! Sorry @jayadevkv, and thanks so much for your time and help!!!!!!!